# i want to make video 2x speed using moviepy but its making videos zoom in,enlarge

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I'm new to moviepy
my requirement is to make a normal video into 2x.
All the videos are recorded on the phone and the videos which are not required any rotations are working fine.
By the videos which are needed to be rotated even, I apply rotation or even just trying to write the outup is zoomed in with full screen
here is the code

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

from moviepy.audio import *

import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx

clip = VideoFileClip("testingggg.mp4",audio=False) 

clip.size

#clip = clip.rotate(90) 

print("Duration of video : ", clip.duration)

print("Duration of video : ", clip.reader.fps)

clip = clip.speedx(2)

#clip = VideoFileClip("final.mp4",audio=False) 

#clip.size


clip.write_videofile("final.mp4", threads=4, audio_fps=44100,codec = 'libx264')
```

hope someone can help me
here are some images so that u can get an idea on my issue
[image: image of original file]
[image: output is in this way]
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's because your original_video is not 1920x1080.
you can use resize((1920, 1080)) to convert the Resolution to 1080p.

```
clip1 = clip.speedx(0.5).resize([1920, 1080])
```

try those code:

```
    
from moviepy.editor import *
import time as tt

# your fpath
fpath =  "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\crawl\\videos\\Cat doesn't finish Vegetables-736fiBMtADg\\Cat doesn't finish Vegetables-736fiBMtADg.mp4"

clip = VideoFileClip(fpath)
print('clip.size: ', clip.size)
# [720, 720]

print("Duration of video : ", clip.duration)
print("Duration of video : ", clip.reader.fps)

clip1 = clip.speedx(0.5).resize([1920, 1080])
print('clip1.size: ', clip.size)
# [1920, 1080]
print("Duration of clip1 : ", clip1.duration)
print("Duration of clip1 : ", clip1.reader.fps)


tmp_mp4 = '__temp__.mp4'        # temporary file

clip1.write_videofile(tmp_mp4)
tt.sleep(0.5)
os.system('explorer ' + tmp_mp4)    # open the file: tmp_mp4.
```